# logout page doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to implement a logout button that logs out a current user but Heroku keeps returning an error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

This is the code for the _header.html.erb view:

```
<li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path,
                                       data: { "turbo-method": :delete } %></li>
```

Code for the config.rb routes:

```
root "trips#index"
...
delete "/logout",  to: "sessions#destroy"
```

Code for the sessions_controller.rb controller:

```
def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url, status: :see_other
  end
```

Code for the sessions_helper.rb helper:

```
def log_out
    @current_user = nil
    reset_session
  end
```

I am not sure why I am getting an error that the page doesn't exist even though I have the logout and root links in my routes file.

I tried to click a button in the header and log out and expected the page to log out the current user and redirect to the root page.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Heroku thinks you are performing a GET request, so something is happening with Turbo. We'll need to see server logs of a click of that button to know more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.